# Print horizontally with write.table command

Tags: r

Here i am writing a small code where number needs to be printed horizantally in the txt file which is been generated here as "note.txt"

```
for(n in 1:4)
 {
 write.table(n,"note.txt",append = TRUE)
 }
```

I am getting output like

```
"x"
"1" 1
"x"
"1" 2
"x"
"1" 3
"x"
"1" 4
```

Whereas i want output as :

```
1 2 3 4
```

or

```
1,2,3,4
```

Please help me.

Comment: You may not need a loop `write.table(as.data.frame.list(1:4), 'note.txt', col.names=FALSE, row.names=FLSE, quote=FALSE)` gives the expected output

Comment: Or just `cat(1:4,file="note.txt")` (or `cat(1:4,file="note.txt",sep=",")` if you want the values separated by a comma).

Answer (score 0):

**Paste function** in R can be used to combine a vector/strings using a separator ( Use the attribute `collapse` in paste command to specify the separator).

If the vector v contains the set of numbers to be printed horizontally.

```
v=c(1:4);
write(paste(as.character(v), collapse=","),"note.txt",append="TRUE";
```